# How to install external packages in W32TeX

Tags: packages, installing, windows

How to install external packages like truncate or natbib in W32Tex ?

I am running the following command to install packages

```
texinstwin "dir of packages"
```

But when I download packages from CTAN and put them in the dir, I get the error

```
No packages installed
```

So how do I install external packages ?

Comment: Did you texhash after putting them in the proper directory?

Comment: @AFeldman What does that mean

Comment: There is not a smart installer of packages in W32TeX.
You have to install additional packages completely
manually in $TEXMFLOCAL. The knowledge of the TeX
Directory Structure (TDS) is needed. I recommend to
use TeX Live or MiKTeX if it is difficult to add
packages or fonts.

Comment: If its just a *.sty file then you can put it in in a /texmf directory and then run the program "texhash" which tells your tex installation to search for new packages  to use.